# if(isset($_POST['submit'])) function responds to button but not to input type=submit

Tags: php, html, forms

Well, as the title already says, I'm not getting it. Probebly doing something very stupid.

This is the form that I'm using. Its not that special. For testing purpose it now has a `<button action=submit...>` and a `<input type=submit...>` line.

```
<div id="cd-login">
<form method="POST" action="index.php" class="cd-form">
    <p class="fieldset">
        <label class="image-replace cd-email" for="signin-email">E-mail</label>
        <input name="login" class="full-width has-padding has-border" type="text" placeholder="Username or E-Mail">
        <span class="cd-error-message">Error message here!</span>
    </p>
    <p class="fieldset">
        <label class="image-replace cd-password" for="signin-password">Password</label>
        <input name="password" class="full-width has-padding has-border" type="password"  placeholder="Password">
        <span class="cd-error-message">Error message here!</span>
    </p>
    <p class="fieldset">
        <input type="checkbox" name="remember_me" id="remember-me"/>
        <label for="remember_me" onclick="document.getElementById('remember_me').click();">Remember Me</label>
    </p>
    <p class="fieldset">
        <input class="full-width" type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" />
        <br />
        <button name="submit">Log In</button>
    </p>
</form>
```

It then goes to the PHP code which is alligned above the HTML code:

```
<?php
require "config.php";
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $identification = $_POST['login'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    if($identification == "" || $password == ""){
        $msg = array("Error", "Username / Password Wrong !");
    }else{
        $login = \Fr\LS::login($identification, $password, isset($_POST['remember_me']));
        if($login === false){
            $msg = array("Error", "Username / Password Wrong !");
        }else if(is_array($login) && $login['status'] == "blocked"){
            $msg = array("Error", "Too many login attempts. You can attempt login after ". $login['minutes'] ." minutes (". $login['seconds'] ." seconds)");
        }
    }
}
?>
```

When I smack my finger on the button it works, but I want to get it to work with an input line.

**EDIT:** Doesn't work in IE, Mozilla or Chrome. The `<input type=submit ...>` is clickeble. But smashing the enter-key doesn't work either.

Comment: If you remove the button from the HTML but leave the input `type='submit'` and `name='submit'`, does `isset($_POST['submit'])` equal `true`? Also, how do you trigger the submission without a button? Pressing `ENTER` on the keyboard?

Comment: Under which browser you get this issue?

Answer (score 0):

replace

```html
<button name="submit">Log In</button>
```

by :

```html
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Log In"/>
```

and eliminate the other input over :)

Comment: Not really sure what you mean. Got it now like :

`<p class="fieldset">
            <input class="full-width" type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" />
            <br />
            <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Log In"/>
        </p>`

Comment: like : <p class="fieldset">
        <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Log In"/>

Comment: if you use the code you mention in your comment you have two submit

Comment: if you want to use the attribut class , its simple :<p class="fieldset"> <input class="full-width" name="submit" type="submit" value="Log In"/>I wish I can help you

Answer (score 0):

When I gave each button/input a unique name, and then checked for that name in POST in your index.php page, I was able to detect which button was pressed.

In principle, it's the name of the item on the form that helps us find it in the POST variables.  When troubleshooting forms like this, you can always var dump the POST array and see what the computer is receiving on the processing page.

As an example, a slightly modified copy of your code is presented below.  I ran your form in the following html.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="cd-login">
<form method="POST" action="index.php" class="cd-form">
<p class="fieldset">
    <label class="image-replace cd-email" for="signin-email">E-mail</label>
    <input name="login" class="full-width has-padding has-border" type="text" placeholder="Username or E-Mail">
    <span class="cd-error-message">Error message here!</span>
</p>
<p class="fieldset">
    <label class="image-replace cd-password" for="signin-password">Password</label>
    <input name="password" class="full-width has-padding has-border" type="password"  placeholder="Password">
    <span class="cd-error-message">Error message here!</span>
</p>
<p class="fieldset">
    <input type="checkbox" name="remember_me" id="remember-me"/>
    <label for="remember_me" onclick="document.getElementById('remember_me').click();">Remember Me</label>
</p>
<p class="fieldset">
    <input class="full-width" type="submit" name="submit1" value="Login" />
    <br />
    <button name="submit2">Log In</button>
</p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Then, I modified the processing page to catch that name in POST with the isset and provide some printing that will show the change is working.  I commented out that config.php because I did not have it.

```
<?php
//require "config.php";
if(isset($_POST['submit1'])){

print ("<p>Hello from Submit1</p>");
var_dump($_POST);

$identification = $_POST['login'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
if($identification == "" || $password == ""){
    $msg = array("Error", "Username / Password Wrong !");
}else{
    $login = \Fr\LS::login($identification, $password, isset($_POST['remember_me']));
    if($login === false){
        $msg = array("Error", "Username / Password Wrong !");
    }else if(is_array($login) && $login['status'] == "blocked"){
        $msg = array("Error", "Too many login attempts. You can attempt login after ". $login['minutes'] ." minutes (". $login['seconds'] ." seconds)");
    }
}
} else {
print ("<p>Submit1 was not recognized.</p>");
var_dump($_POST);
}
?>
```

When I ran that code, I could show the difference in the two buttons.